# Save dynamically data to localStorage and load this data in a html table when .html loads

Tags: javascript, html-table

I got this project for school, I need to load data from sessionStorage in a html table when my .html loads (not only from cache).

I insert new data in sessionStorage from another .html, i need to save it dynamically (for example the first row of my table is rfc0, razon_social0, direccion_fiscal0, the next row is rfc1, razon_social1, direccion_fiscal1, etc...), I use this Javascript function to save my data:

```
function getInfo() {
    if (sessionStorage.contador){
        var i = parseInt(sessionStorage.contador);
    }
    else{
        sessionStorage.setItem('contador', "0");
        var i = parseInt(sessionStorage.contador);
    }

    var rfc = document.getElementById('RFC').value.toUpperCase(); 
    sessionStorage.setItem('rfc' + i, rfc);

    var razon_social = document.getElementById('razon_social').value;
    sessionStorage.setItem('razon_social' + i, razon_social);

    var domicilio_fiscal = document.getElementById('domicilio_fiscal').value;
    sessionStorage.setItem('domicilio_fiscal' + i, domicilio_fiscal);

    var banco = document.getElementById('banco').value;
    sessionStorage.setItem('banco' + i, banco);

    var numero_cuenta = document.getElementById('numero_cuenta').value;
    sessionStorage.setItem('numero_cuenta' + i, numero_cuenta);
    i++;
    sessionStorage.setItem('contador', i);
}
```

In my body onpageshow I use this function to check the Storage support and call the data:

```
function checkStorage() {
    if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
        if(sessionStorage.flag) {
            agregarDatos();
        }
    }
     else {
        alert('Sorry! No Web Storage support...')
    }
}
```

My function agregarDatos() is:

```
function agregarDatos() {
    var table = document.getElementById("tabla_clientes");
    var i = parseInt(sessionStorage.contador);
    var conta = 0;
    while(conta <= i){ 
        var row = table.insertRow(-1);
        var cell0 = row.insertCell(0)
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(1);
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(2);
        var cell3 = row.insertCell(3);
        var cell4 = row.insertCell(4);
        cell0.innerHTML = '<input class="check" type="checkbox" onClick="validateButton()">';
        cell1.innerHTML = sessionStorage.getItem('rfc' + conta);
        cell2.innerHTML = sessionStorage.getItem('razon_social' + conta);
        cell3.innerHTML = sessionStorage.getItem('domicilio_fiscal' + conta);
        cell4.innerHTML = '<input class="editar" type="button" value="Editar">';
        conta++;
    }
}
```

When I test this, got nothing even when I add an element from the first time, I can't figure what's wrong.

If I save the data without ID I can only add one row with the last data stored.

P.D. Only I can use Javascript...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has a couple of errors:

1. In order to populate the table you are checking the value of `sessionStorage.flag` that is not set anywhere in your code. As it is not defined, the `if` condition is false and `agregarDatos()` will never be called. **To fix this** check for `sessionStorage.contador` (as it is done in the JSFiddle specified below)
2. In `agregarDatos()` the loop goes one extra iteration because you are doing `conta <= i` when you should be doing `conta < i`.

This would be the code (with some mock HTML and `getInfo` call). The modified lines are pointed with comments:

```js
function getInfo() {
    if (sessionStorage.contador){
        var i = parseInt(sessionStorage.contador);
    } else {
        sessionStorage.setItem('contador', "0");
        var i = parseInt(sessionStorage.contador);
    }
    
    var rfc = document.getElementById('RFC').value.toUpperCase(); 
    sessionStorage.setItem('rfc' + i, rfc);
    
    var razon_social = document.getElementById('razon_social').value;
    sessionStorage.setItem('razon_social' + i, razon_social);
    
    var domicilio_fiscal = document.getElementById('domicilio_fiscal').value;
    sessionStorage.setItem('domicilio_fiscal' + i, domicilio_fiscal);
    
    var banco = document.getElementById('banco').value;
    sessionStorage.setItem('banco' + i, banco);
    
    var numero_cuenta = document.getElementById('numero_cuenta').value;
    sessionStorage.setItem('numero_cuenta' + i, numero_cuenta);
    i++;
    sessionStorage.setItem('contador', i);
}

function agregarDatos() {
    var table = document.getElementById("tabla_clientes");
    var i = parseInt(sessionStorage.contador);
    var conta = 0;

    // Loop from 0 to elems-1 (before it was iterating one extra time)
    while(conta < i){ 
        var row = table.insertRow(-1);
        var cell0 = row.insertCell(0)
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(1);
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(2);
        var cell3 = row.insertCell(3);
        var cell4 = row.insertCell(4);
        cell0.innerHTML = '<input class="check" type="checkbox" onClick="validateButton()">';
        cell1.innerHTML = sessionStorage.getItem('rfc' + conta);
        cell2.innerHTML = sessionStorage.getItem('razon_social' + conta);
        cell3.innerHTML = sessionStorage.getItem('domicilio_fiscal' + conta);
        cell4.innerHTML = '<input class="editar" type="button" value="Editar">';
        conta++;
    }
}

function checkStorage() {
    if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
        // sessionStorage.flag does not exist, use a value that you know will exist
        if(sessionStorage.contador) {
            agregarDatos();
        }
    }
     else {
        alert('Sorry! No Web Storage support...')
    }
}

window.onload = function() {
    console.log(1);
    checkStorage();
}
```

```html
<div>
    <input type="text" id="RFC" placeholder="RFC" /><br/>
    <input type="text" id="razon_social" placeholder="Razón Social"/><br/>
    <input type="text" id="domicilio_fiscal" placeholder="Domicilio Fiscal"/><br/>
    <input type="text" id="banco" placeholder="Banco"/><br/>
    <input type="text" id="numero_cuenta" placeholder="Número de Cuenta"/><br/>
    <input type="button" value="Add to table" onclick="getInfo()"/>
</div>
<table id="tabla_clientes"></table>
```

That window is sandboxed so you cannot see it working on here, but you can on this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jd0pjw15/3/).

Comment: the statement for `conta < = i` is ,I think, true, because the index 'contador' is initiated from '0'

Comment: `sessionStorage.contador` is also initialized to 0, and it holds the number of elements saved in the storage. So if for example there are 3 elements, `sessionStorage.contador` value will be 3, and `conta` will have to loop from 0 to 2, but with the original code it loops from 0 to 3, and the last one will be empty