# prevent added tables from disappearing when page is refreshed

Tags: javascript, html

basically, when user entered some values in each added rows, those values and the number of added rows don't disappear... how is that possible?

here's my code:

```js
function delPlace(row) {
  var txtb = document.getElementById('travel');
  var len = txtb.rows.length;
  if (len > 2) {
    var i = row.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
    document.getElementById('travel').deleteRow(i);
  } else {
    alert("Can't delete all rows. One row must at least remain.");
  }
}
function addPlace() {
  var txtb = document.getElementById('travel');
  var add_row = txtb.rows[1].cloneNode(true);
  var len = txtb.rows.length;
  add_row.cells[0].innerHTML = len;

  var inp = add_row.cells[1].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
  inp.id += len;
  inp.value = '';
  txtb.appendChild(add_row);
}
```

```html
<table id="travel">
  <p> List the countries/cities the person had traveled to/from in the past 15 days before diagnosis </p>
  <tr><input type="button" id="add_place" value="Add" onclick="addPlace()" /></tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="display:none"></td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="travel_history[]" value="" placeholder="Enter text here..."
        style="width:500px">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="button" id="del_place" value="Remove" onclick="delPlace(this)" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: You'll need to store the table state in local/session storage.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Save dynamically data to localStorage and load this data in a html table when .html loads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31508480/save-dynamically-data-to-localstorage-and-load-this-data-in-a-html-table-when-h)